# Azure App fails to push: kudu.dll: not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I've been using git to deploy a PHP Azure WebApp from Visual Studio.
Suddenly, when I try to push, I get the following error:

```
Ivans-MacBook-Pro-4:myapp ivan$ git push azure master
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 537 bytes | 537.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hooks/post-receive: 4: hooks/post-receive: /opt/Kudu/KuduConsole/kudu.dll: not found
To https://ivandemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/ivandemoapp.git
   76c077f..ed6bddd  master -> master
```

I haven't found any valid suggestions in other questions.
What can I do?

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Visit your kudu website, https://ivandemoapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui .

Use `rm` to delete everything inside `/home` folder. Then try to redeploy your web app.